Write/convert the oracle data to Json format using SSIS


 using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(manifestFilePath, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("manifest");

            writer.WriteElementString("processType", "DataIngest");
            writer.WriteElementString("totalRecordCount", totalRecordCount.ToString());

            writer.WriteStartElement("files");

            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("file");
                writer.WriteElementString("name", fileName);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement(); // End files
            writer.WriteEndElement(); // End manifest
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }



I am looking for some help to read the data from the Oracle source and write it to flat file in the .json format. Since there is a huge volume of data, data should be split into multiple json files. And once the process is completed, need to generate a completed file with number of rows processed
Used data flow task and selected oracle source. Need a c# logic to convert the data into json format and write to a file.



using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    private StreamWriter fileWriter;
    private int fileCounter = 1;
    private int rowCounter = 0;
    private int rowsPerFile = 1000;  // Set the number of rows per file

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        OpenNewFile();
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        fileWriter.Close();
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        var rowData = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 column in this.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection)
        {
            var columnName = column.Name;
            var columnValue = Row.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(Row, null);
            rowData.Add(columnName, columnValue);
        }

        string json = SerializeToJson(rowData);
        fileWriter.WriteLine(json);
        rowCounter++;

        if (rowCounter >= rowsPerFile)
        {
            fileWriter.Close();
            fileCounter++;
            rowCounter = 0;
            OpenNewFile();
        }
    }

    private void OpenNewFile()
    {
        string filePath = $"C:\\PathToYourFolder\\output_{fileCounter}.json";  // Set your file path
        fileWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    private string SerializeToJson(Dictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        json.Append("{");

        foreach (var kvp in data)
        {
            json.Append($"\"{kvp.Key}\": \"{kvp.Value}\",");
        }

        if (json.Length > 1)
        {
            json.Length--;  // Remove the last comma
        }

        json.Append("}");
        return json.ToString();
    }
}





//manifest format

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<manifest>
 <processType>DataIngest</processType>
 <totalRecordCount>13000</totalRecordCount>
 <files>
  <file>
   <name>/AccountDataIngestion-20240624092345_123_1.json</name>
  </file>
  <file>
   <name>/AccountDataIngestion_20240624092345_234._2json</name> 
  </file>
 </files>
</manifest>




What version of Oracle?  Latest versions have a lot of built-in features for handling JSON data.  Please [edit] your question to provide more details, including what you've attempted so far, the table definition, what column(s) in the table would you be accessing, etc.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have used the data flow task and connect to oracle source. Then I have used script component and selected all the columns from the input column tab. I have used the C# code provided above. I am getting below error

[Script Component [360]] Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception e)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProcessInput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 inputID, IDTSBuffer100 pDTSBuffer, IntPtr bufferWirePacket)
